# Preventing Others From Connecting To WebSocket On NodeJS? (WS Module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, websocket, socket.io

I am currently experimenting with websockets on NodeJS and am wondering if its possible to protect/secure my websocket. I'd like to be able to prevent others from connecting to my websocket and using the data that is being sent from it. If I have a website that recieves data from this NodeJS websocket, is there anyway to ensure that only my domain (mydomain.com) or website can read this data and not any other client/website? I am currently using the WS module found on NPM. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Server Code:

```
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server
  wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8000})
  wss.on('connection', function (ws) { })
```

Client (JavaScript) Code:

```
 var wss = new WebSocket('wss://mydomain.com'); 
    wss.onmessage = function(e) {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.data); }
```

Comment: The auth token is not hardcoded in your code. Instead, you would usually perform a conventional HTTP authentication to retrieve it first and it would be different for every client/session.

Comment: You can also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965210/configuring-authentication-headers-for-websocket-connection

Comment: Okay, great, thank you! I will take a look at this.